# How to quickly determine if $n^n \geq a$, if $a$ and $n$ are given

Tags: inequality

Sorry for my English. How can I quicky determine if $n^n \geq a$. I need to use it in programming (if there are efficient algorithms)

Comment: And if n < a? Meanwhile n is about 10^9

Comment: Assuming the two numbers are positive, $n^n>a\iff n\log n>\log a$.

Comment: What programming task needs this? I'm curious.

Comment: In what form are $n$ and $a$ given as input? What range of numbers are they from?

Answer (score 3):

The solution of the equation $n^n=a$ is given by $$n=\frac{\log (a)}{W(\log (a))}$$ where appears Lambert function.

I you look at the Wikipedia page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), you will find good approximations in particular for the case where the argument is large. At the very first order, $$W(x)\approx L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}$$ where $L_1=\log(x)$, $L_2=\log(L_1)$.

Let us try with $a=10^{12}$. The above approximation gives $W(\log(10^{12}))=2.48075$ and so, $n=11.1382$ while the exact solution is $11.3673$. For sure, using more terms would lead to a closer value. For example, using the next term of the expansion

$$W(x)\approx L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\frac{L_2(L_2-2)}{2L_1^2}$$ would lead to  $W(\log(10^{12}))=2.43717$ and $n=11.3374$

Comment: I understood that it was for a programming exercise. Is it so complex ? Cheers.